# Vuetify - Ability to select parent nodes without opening them

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to be able to select the parent nodes in Treeview without opening the node to reveal its children?

At the moment when you click on a parent node it opens up revealing the children.

What if you had the following, and you wanted to select each node to see how many houses had been sold in the last year. So you can search by City, Area and Road name.

Is this at all possible with Treeviw in Vuetify?

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview

```html
items: [
{
    name: 'Manchester',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'Salford',
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Sall Street"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Cholrton',
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Chol Street"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Birmingham",
    children: [
        {
            name: "Handsworth",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Rookery Road"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Erdington",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Brown Street"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

From the "Scoped slots" example you linked in the question:

```
  <v-treeview
            v-model="tree"
            :open="open"
            :items="items"
            activatable
            item-key="name"
            open-on-click
    >
```

If you remove the "open-on-click", you will be able to select parent nodes and expand them by clicking on the arrow.

Note, if expanded, selecting the parent node also selects the children.